# AndroidViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am trying to create an instance of my AndroidViewModel in MainActivity. When I do this I get the following error **has no zero argument constructor**

Here is my RecipeViewModel

```
package com.example.kookrecepten;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

public class RecipeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Recipe>> allRecipes;

    public RecipeViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        recipeRepository = new RecipeRepository(application);
        allRecipes = recipeRepository.getAllRecipes();
    }

    public void insert(Recipe recipe) {
        recipeRepository.insert(recipe);
    }

    public void update(Recipe recipe) {
        recipeRepository.update(recipe);
    }

    public void delete(Recipe recipe) {
        recipeRepository.delete(recipe);
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        recipeRepository.deleteAllRecipes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Recipe>> getAllRecipes() {
        return allRecipes;
    }
}
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong but AndroidViewModel needs the Application context in the constructor and ViewModel doesn't. So I have no idea why android asks for a zero arguments constructor.

Here is my Main activity where I ask for an instance.

```
package com.example.kookrecepten;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.kookrecepten.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private RecipeViewModel recipeViewModel;

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        //Get an instance of the RecipeViewModel.
        recipeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecipeViewModel.class);
        recipeViewModel.getAllRecipes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Recipe> recipes) {
                //Update recycle view

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this are my implementations.

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def room_version = "2.2.5"

//LifeCycle Components
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    //Room Components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: make sure you have to @AndroidEntryPoint in your activity

Answer (score 56, accepted):

if you're using `hilt`, you probably forgot to annotate your activity with `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Comment: Thanks after hours, I got your post and I realize i forgot to mention @AndroidEntryPoint.

Comment: In my case I have added @AndroidEntryPoint to my base activity and it was crashing, setting it on each activity worked. But in my dagger project I have did AndroidInjection only on baseactivity

Comment: I got the same "has no zero argument constructor" error because I had not added    
     kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
to my build.gradle file

Comment: @user3433200 after 2 hours, I came here to say the same and then saw that I had overlooked your comment earlier...

Answer (score 17):

apparently if I change

```
recipeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecipeViewModel.class);
```

to this

```
recipeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(RecipeViewModel.class);
```

It works. I don't know why this solution works could someone explain?

Comment: This is caused by a version mismatch between activity-ktx and lifecycle-ktx. It makes your `AppCompatActivity` not implement `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`, and this results in this odd behavior. You should not need to manually grab the "original default" as this way your default is not a `SavedStateViewModelFactory`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, so, concretely what is the solution, since I have the same issue ? I just discovered ViewModel and I'm not guru yet ;-)

Comment: @gduh use the first one, not the second one, but update your AndroidX dependencies to the latest - and explicitly add androidx.fragment and androidx.activity and androidx.core's latest non-alpha versions, along with lifecycle being at least 2.2.0.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have already check all your recommandations, but using AndroidViewModel, the app still crashes with the same message "has no zero argument constructor". For now, I have no other solution than to use the second one.

Comment: @gduh feel free to create a new question, make sure to add the exception stack trace, the ViewModel, and the build.gradle dependencies. Also important to know if you're using Hilt, because that can mess with it too with some missing deps.

Comment: @Ruben thank you so much bro you really saved my life

Comment: because this will initialize the default constructor of AndroidViewModel in which application context is recived, i think if you init the default const by normal code than the first one may also work (not sure).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look to Android Source code. If your activity was extending the class `Activity`, instead of `AppCompatActivity` you wouldn't have seen this issue.  The class `Activity` provides an implementation for the interface `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory` which provides a correct factory for classes extending AndroidViewModel. Unfortunately, `AppCompatActivity` still doesn't implement that interface, and then, no correct factory is available. So, either you provide the factory as you did, or you might implement by yourself the interface `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the old, deprecated

```
recipeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RecipeViewModel.class);
```

This definitely used to work in our applications. If you're the adventureous type, you can also use the debugger and step into the get() method of the ViewModelProvider to check how it attempts to get an instance of the viewmodel.